# I built a Database and scafolded the tables I need but I Realized there is a table which one of his attribute is not needed anymore

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I built a Database and scaffolded the tables I need  but I Realized there is a table in which one of his attributes is not needed anymore
how can I delete these attributes without casing any problem they are not a primary key or foreign key or an important attribute

Comment: What do they look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Code-first` approach, you just need to delete that attribute which you don't need it anymore. Then Add a new Migration like this:

```
Add-Migration RemovePropertyFromTablex
```

after generating new Migration, update your database:

```
Update-Database
```